# Trying to understand the usefulness of the delta-epsilon definitions of limits

Tags: calculus, limits, soft-question, definition, epsilon-delta

I am trying to wrap my head around the formal definition of a limit using the delta-epsilon approach, which I'll repeat below for convenience:

> Suppose that $L$ and $c$ are real numbers and $f$ is a real-valued function defined on some open interval containing $c$. We say that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c} f(x) =L}$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $0 < |x - c| < \delta$, then $|f(x) -L| < \epsilon$.

More informally, $|a - b|$ is like saying "the distance between $a$ and $b$", so I'd like to rephrase the definition in my own informal interpretation:

> I can give you a positive real $\epsilon$, defining a threshold on the
>   $y$-axis centered on $y=L$, where the threshold is of size
>   $\epsilon$ on the top and bottom. And no matter what value I give you,
>   you can give me back another positive real $\delta$ that describes a
>   similar horizontal threshold on the $x$-axis centered on $x=c$, where
>   the threshold is of size $\delta$ on the left and right.
>
> Moreover, for every $x$ coordinate in this $\delta$ threshold, the $y$
>   coordinates of the corresponding points in $f$ fall entirely inside
>   the $\epsilon$ threshold.

To my eye this suggests an infinite recursion. Because the threshold that $\delta$ maps to falls within $\epsilon$, whatever that new threshold is would become a new $\epsilon$ that is even smaller, and we'd repeat this process over again, forever.

As $x$ and $c$ get closer and closer, so do $f(x)$ and $L$. Maybe they get closer together at different rates, but as far as I can tell this only says that these two quantities can get closer and closer *indefinitely*. But what bothers me is that we're saying we can make these closer and closer but say absolutely nothing about what happens at $f(c)$. The limit would be the same even if we removed the point (assuming it was defined). The definition only references what's going on around the point -- the point itself is almost an afterthought.

What I struggle with now is trying to understand how this becomes a useful definition that underlies almost everything in calculus, when the entire concept appears to be about what's happening *around* something but not *on* it. What problem is this addressing? What niche is it filling?

Comment: What are you comparing this definition of limits with? Assuming you agree that limits are useful, you need a precise definition of what limits *are*, and one which is practical, in the sense that one can use it without a lot of troubles. What alternative definition you have considered?

Comment: You are trying to understand the result of several centuries of humankind trying to come up with a coherent, consistent and practical definition of what approaching means. It certainly sounds like you have learned about this quite recently. My emphatic suggestion is that you suspend disbelief for, say, a semester, and learn actual calculus, see the definition in use, see the applications of that use and then, only then start worrying about niches and what not.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm not a student; graduated a long time ago. I've always been able to solve basic calculus problems but without really understanding the mechanics, which I've become more interested in recently. But I'm struggling to understand the utility of this definition outside of "it happens to work and give us the right answers for a variety of problems"

Comment: You must certainly appreciate that come out of the blue and assuming that the definition of limits, the very basic piece upon which the whole of modern calculus is built —and this is probably the most successful and widely used part of mathematics— is there «to fill a niche» is somewhat preposterous...

Comment: I mean "niche" in a very broad sense, as in "We can't solve this problem, we need a new mathematical framework, poof, here's Calculus, how does it work? Well here's this delta-epsilon thing. What does it let us do?"

Comment: But the utility of a definition resides precisely in that it happens to work and gives the right answers for many problems!

Comment: The epsilon-delta definition is a precise, consistent and practical definition of what a limit is. That's what it lets us do: it define precisely something we want to have precisely defined.

Comment: I agree, it defines what a limit is, but my question is different from that. I'm asking why this is a useful definition other than "it happens to give us the right answers to things" (which feels very "faith-based" to me). I'm trying to ascertain what problem is being directly addressed with this definition and how it ends up being resolved.

Comment: You seem to believe that there is something else apart from being useful and practical that we use to judge definitions. There isn't.

Comment: Would you be happier if the definition omitted the requirement that $0<|x-c|$, so $x=c$ was included?  That would actually not be a substantial change to the definition (the definition would be essentially though not literally equivalent and you could do all the same things with it).

Comment: If you want to ascertain what problem is being addressed with this definition, comparinge it to the other definitions: you'll notice that they are non-existent (apart from nonstandard calculus, which gets that name because it is nonstandard)

Comment: @eric, well, many limits would cease to exist!

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm not sure; I'd only be able to answer that question after understanding why it works just fine even with the point being excluded. I feel like much would change with that new definition.

Comment: That definition would not make sense of derivatives, for example, as the incremental quotient is simply not defined at the point.

Comment: Let us call that modification a "strong limit".  Then $L$ is the strong limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to c$ iff $L$ is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to c$ in the usual sense and also $f(c)=L$.  So the concept is completely interchangeable with the usual one, it just also tests whether $f(c)$ is equal to $L$.  (And if you want to use the old definition in situations where $f(c)$ might not be equal to $L$, you just have to define a new function $g$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\neq c$ and $g(c)=L$.)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I understand what you're saying but I'm explaining myself poorly, my question is different and I'm not sure how to word it better. I'm trying to say something like "this concept of a limit only describes activity around something, within tolerance of something, in a sort of hazy field around something, a neighborhood -- and yet we can somehow use this to get very exact answers to things"

Comment: The limit is usually introduced specifically to talk about the behavior of a function around but not at a point. Could you perhaps edit your original post and give an example of where you feel this definition is insufficient because it says nothing about the behavior at the point you are approaching?

Comment: This notion of "strong limit" is less convenient than the usual definition for some applications (such as derivatives), but more convenient for others (such as continuity).

Comment: I'd say that an 98% of the point of limits is that they do not depend on the value of the function at the point. If calculus classes don't manage to give a hint of that, then sigh.

Comment: That is not what I am asking

Comment: Well the ideas of calculus in their primitive form started long back in the time of Archimedes and these people used it successfully to find areas and volumes of various geometrical figures not made of straight lines. The essential idea which they understood was the theory of real numbers which was largely forgotten and redeveloped in 19th century.

Answer (score 1):

We require a punctured neighborhood in the definition of a limit precisely so we can distinguish behavior *near* a point from behavior *at* a point.

This distinction is crucial to differential calculus, for example, because we want to define the slope of the tangent line *at* a point (say $x=a$) to be the limit of the slope of secant line approximations *near* that point—but the slope of the secant line is

$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

When we let $x$ "approach" or "tend to" $a$, we better not require the $\epsilon$ condition to be satisfied at *every* point in some interval around $a$, because the above expression isn't defined when $x=a$! So instead we delete the point $x=a$ from consideration.

If our definition required the $\epsilon$ condition to be satisfied at all points in some interval around $a$, limits would exist only for continuous functions—functions for which behavior *near* a point coincides with behavior *at* the point.

Comment: That is where I have trouble. I understand how to solve the expressions and why we exclude the point, etc. But I think what bothers me is that it still feels like no matter what we're getting an "approximation" even though it can get better and better depending on how close we bring $x$ and $a$ together, and yet the slope we extract is a very hard, exact number that we use as an input in other problems and situations even though our limit definition says we never actually computed that particular thing, just everything around it.

Comment: Since $\varepsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, you may think of it as an "infinitely precise" approximation if you would like.

Comment: You did not understand "why we exclude the point" in your post, because you asked why we do so. I have told you what problem needs addressing—the conceptual motivation for distinguishing behavior at a point from behavior near a point. Now you are asking another question entirely, and a terribly vague and confused one at that.

Comment: No, I understand _that_ we exclude the points, and I understand that in situations like these we exclude it because we end up with div-$0$'s and such. (I've solved plenty of calculus problems), I'm trying to find a proper way to word the question. It's the same question, I'm just not sure how to phrase it.

Comment: Perhaps "How do we use this definition of describing something around a point to then turn around and say something useful about that specific point?"

Comment: You asked why we care about distinguishing behavior at a point from behavior "around" a point—why that need arises. I've answered that question. You might do well to stop using silly language like "very hard, exact number." Numbers aren't hard or exact. The limit of the difference quotient, if it exists, is a real number (assuming a real valued function), yes. So what?

Comment: We care about it because the expressions aren't able to be evaluated otherwise. I understand the need. But just because the need arises, what makes this framework a "correct' way to address that need?

Comment: I suggest you read a real calculus book and stop asking different questions. Try Spivak's Calculus.

Comment: @ArukaJ: Regarding your first comment above: we **did compute** the particular thing, and we did it **by** looking at everything around it; that's the whole point.